# Sorting an array of objects numerically using inline function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, numbers

I have a js object array which i need to sort based on area h*w. that is, each object has {h,w}. I am not getting the sorted array.

I have an array as shown,

```js
var blocks = [];

blocks.push({
  w: 320,
  h: 135
});
blocks.push({
  w: 320,
  h: 270
});
blocks.push({
  w: 320,
  h: 135
});
blocks.push({
  w: 320,
  h: 135
});
blocks.push({
  w: 320,
  h: 135
});

blocks.sort(function(a, b) {
  return (b.w * b.h < a.w * a.h);
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(blocks));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the minus operator, check this snippet

```js
  var blocks=[]
  blocks.push({
        w: 320,
        h: 135
    });
    blocks.push({
        w: 320,
        h: 270
    });        
        blocks.push({
        w: 320,
        h: 135
    });
        blocks.push({
        w: 320,
        h: 135
    });
        blocks.push({
        w: 320,
        h: 135
    });

blocks.sort(function(a, b) {
            return (b.w * b.h - a.w * a.h);
        });
console.log(blocks);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-` operator:

```
blocks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.w * b.h - a.w * a.h;
});
```

If `sort`'s callback returns:

- a negative number, then `sort` will place `a` before `b`
- `0`, then `a` and `b` are equal and `sort` will decide who comes before whom.
- a positive number, then `sort` will place `b` before `a`.

**Note:** The above code sorts the array in descending order, if you want to reverse the sort order, then just return `a.w * a.h - b.w * b.h` instead.